# How to send values from html form to mail in table PHP

Tags: php, forms, html-table, html-email

This what I have I tried to put it in a table just like:

```
<table>
<tr><td>$_POST['onderwerp']</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have it sends the mail but it's to messy:

```
<?php

$to      = 'example@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Vraag via de website';

$message = 'Onderwerp:'. $_POST['onderwerp'].'<br /><br />'.$_POST['vraag'].'<br /><br />'.'Telefoonummer:'. $_POST['tel'].'<br /><br />'.'Email:'. $_POST['email'] ;



$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";



// Additional headers

$headers .= 'To:<eexample@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'The shop<example@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";





mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: contact.html');

?>
```

I just want to send the variables in a table so that I don't have to search through all the text.

Comment: how to send the mail with a html table

Comment: do you want the variables in a html table?

Comment: yes so i can read it in gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$to = 'user@example.com';
$subject = 'Vraag via de website';
$msg = "<html>
 <head>
 <title>Title of email</title>
 </head>

 <body>

<table cellspacing=\"4\" cellpadding=\"4\" border=\"1\" align=\"center\">

<tr>
<td align=\"center\">Onderwerp</td>
<td align=\"center\"> vraag</td>
<td align=\"center\">Telefoonummer</td>
<td align=\"center\">Email</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align=\"center\">".$_POST['onderwerp']."</td>
<td align=\"center\">".$_POST['vraag']."</td>
<td align=\"center\">".$_POST['tel']."</td>
<td align=\"center\">".$_POST['email']."</td>
</tr>



</table>
</body>
</html>";

// Make sure to escape quotes

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Site Name <me@mysite.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this using your variables.

```
$var = 'test';
$var2 = 'test2';

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><td>' . $var . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>' . $var . '</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

this will show the variables in a table, then you can edit the table using css how you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you include swiftmailer.
Swiftmailer makes sure emails get delivered in the Inbox and you can easily include HTML markup in your emails:

[Swiftmailer HTML in email](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)

Just download the Swiftmailer Library, include and configure it like this example:

[Sending an email in swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html)

Let me know if this helps you out!

Comment: hey jason bedankt voor j comment ik ga het uitproberen

Comment: Succes! laat me weten of het is gelukt!